# Text overlapping after generating a PDF with jsPDF

Tags: angular, typescript, pdf, jspdf, html2canvas

I am trying to generate a PDF using JSPDF library, currently I am facing an issue where some of the text elements are displayed as overlapping(text elements placed over one another, like stacked) other or being misplaced in the document (away from it's expected position). What could be the issue and how may I solve it. Adding .html and .ts (Angular 14) below.

Is it anyhow related to the fonts being used?

```
  public openPDF(): void {
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    let DATA: any = document.getElementById('htmlData'); 

    doc.html(DATA, {
       callback: function (doc) {
        doc.output('dataurlnewwindow');
       },
       html2canvas:{
        scale: 0.18,
        useCORS: true,
        allowTaint: true,
       },
       margin: 5,
       autoPaging: "text",
       fontFaces: []
    });
  }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="col-md-6 my-5 mx-5">
    <button class="btn btn-success btn-block" (click)="openPDF()">Download PDF</button>
</div>
<div class="container">
    <div id="htmlData">
        <h2>Lore Ipsum sans barams</h2>
        <p><strong>API</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dignissim ligula sit amet
            dui elementum placerat. Proin ultricies sollicitudin varius. Etiam erat mauris, eleifend sed risus non,
            vulputate congue sapien. In a orci tempor, venenatis leo vitae, suscipit dolor. Fusce a eros sed magna
            varius semper. Aliquam eget aliquet erat. Donec non sem ac erat consequat finibus. Aenean congue imperdiet
            feugiat. Mauris lobortis, elit in tempor laoreet, libero est bibendum massa, ut fringilla augue enim eget
            velit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Proin ultricies, est eget sodales
            ornare, nulla elit luctus lectus, et pulvinar odio lacus eget tellus.</p>
        <p><strong>Available for</strong>: IPSUM PYPSUM
        </p>
        <h3>Lore Ipsum sans barams</h3>
        <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dignissim ligula sit</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dignissim ligula sit</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dignissim ligula sit</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dignissim ligula sit</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dignissim ligula sit</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dignissim ligula sit</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dignissim ligula sit</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dignissim ligula sit</li>
        </ul>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dignissim ligula sit</p>
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dignissim ligula sit<strong><u>v1</u></strong>/
        </p>
        <p><strong>API</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dignissim ligula sit amet
            dui elementum placerat. Proin ultricies sollicitudin varius. Etiam erat mauris, eleifend sed risus non,
            vulputate congue sapien. In a orci tempor, venenatis leo vitae, suscipit dolor. Fusce a eros sed magna
            varius semper. Aliquam eget aliquet erat. Donec non sem ac erat consequat finibus. Aenean congue imperdiet
            feugiat. Mauris lobortis, elit in tempor laoreet, libero est bibendum massa, ut fringilla augue enim eget
            velit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Proin ultricies, est eget sodales
            ornare, nulla elit luctus lectus, et pulvinar odio lacus eget tellus.</p>
        <h3>Lore Ipsum sans barams</h3>
        <p><strong>API</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dignissim ligula sit amet
            dui elementum placerat. Proin ultricies sollicitudin varius. Etiam erat mauris, eleifend sed risus non,
            vulputate congue sapien. In a orci tempor, venenatis leo vitae, suscipit dolor. Fusce a eros sed magna
            varius semper. Aliquam eget aliquet erat. Donec non sem ac erat consequat finibus. Aenean congue imperdiet
            feugiat. Mauris lobortis, elit in tempor laoreet, libero est bibendum massa, ut fringilla augue enim eget
            velit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Proin ultricies, est eget sodales
            ornare, nulla elit luctus lectus, et pulvinar odio lacus eget tellus.</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dignissim ligula sit</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dignissim ligula sit</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dignissim ligula sit</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dignissim ligula sit</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dignissim ligula sit</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dignissim ligula sit</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dignissim ligula sit</li>
        </ul>
        <p>
        <p><strong>API</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dignissim ligula sit amet
            dui elementum placerat. Proin ultricies sollicitudin varius. Etiam erat mauris, eleifend sed risus non,
            vulputate congue sapien. In a orci tempor, venenatis leo vitae, suscipit dolor. Fusce a eros sed magna
            varius semper. Aliquam eget aliquet erat. Donec non sem ac erat consequat finibus. Aenean congue imperdiet
            feugiat. Mauris lobortis, elit in tempor laoreet, libero est bibendum massa, ut fringilla augue enim eget
            velit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Proin ultricies, est eget sodales
            ornare, nulla elit luctus lectus, et pulvinar odio lacus eget tellus.</p> <b> It’s required to follow best
            practices of API usage:</b>
        <p><strong>API</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dignissim ligula sit amet
            dui elementum placerat. Proin ultricies sollicitudin varius. Etiam erat mauris, eleifend sed risus non,
            vulputate congue sapien. In a orci tempor, venenatis leo vitae, suscipit dolor. Fusce a eros sed magna
            varius semper. Aliquam eget aliquet erat. Donec non sem ac erat consequat finibus. Aenean congue imperdiet
            feugiat. Mauris lobortis, elit in tempor laoreet, libero est bibendum massa, ut fringilla augue enim eget
            velit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Proin ultricies, est eget sodales
            ornare, nulla elit luctus lectus, et pulvinar odio lacus eget tellus.</p>
        <p><strong>API documentation with code examples</strong> is kept in SEB's developer portal:</p>
        <p><a href="https://developer.baltics.sebgroup.com/bgw/apis">https://developer.baltics.sebgroup.com/bgw/apis</a>
        </p>
        <p><strong>API</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dignissim ligula sit amet
            dui elementum placerat. Proin ultricies sollicitudin varius. Etiam erat mauris, eleifend sed risus non,
            vulputate congue sapien. In a orci tempor, venenatis leo vitae, suscipit dolor. Fusce a eros sed magna
            varius semper. Aliquam eget aliquet erat. Donec non sem ac erat consequat finibus. Aenean congue imperdiet
            feugiat. Mauris lobortis, elit in tempor laoreet, libero est bibendum massa, ut fringilla augue enim eget
            velit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Proin ultricies, est eget sodales
            ornare, nulla elit luctus lectus, et pulvinar odio lacus eget tellus.</p>
        <ul>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dignissim ligula sit</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dignissim ligula sit</li>
            <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dignissim ligula sit</li>

        </ul>
        <p><strong>API</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dignissim ligula sit amet
            dui elementum placerat. Proin ultricies sollicitudin varius. Etiam erat mauris, eleifend sed risus non,
            vulputate congue sapien. In a orci tempor, venenatis leo vitae, suscipit dolor. Fusce a eros sed magna
            varius semper. Aliquam eget aliquet erat. Donec non sem ac erat consequat finibus. Aenean congue imperdiet
            feugiat. Mauris lobortis, elit in tempor laoreet, libero est bibendum massa, ut fringilla augue enim eget
            velit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Proin ultricies, est eget sodales
            ornare, nulla elit luctus lectus, et pulvinar odio lacus eget tellus.</p>
        <p><strong>API</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dignissim ligula sit amet
            dui elementum placerat. Proin ultricies sollicitudin varius. Etiam erat mauris, eleifend sed risus non,
            vulputate congue sapien. In a orci tempor, venenatis leo vitae, suscipit dolor. Fusce a eros sed magna
            varius semper. Aliquam eget aliquet erat. Donec non sem ac erat consequat finibus. Aenean congue imperdiet
            feugiat. Mauris lobortis, elit in tempor laoreet, libero est bibendum massa, ut fringilla augue enim eget
            velit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Proin ultricies, est eget sodales
            ornare, nulla elit luctus lectus, et pulvinar odio lacus eget tellus.</p>
        <p><strong>API</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dignissim ligula sit amet
            dui elementum placerat. Proin ultricies sollicitudin varius. Etiam erat mauris, eleifend sed risus non,
            vulputate congue sapien. In a orci tempor, venenatis leo vitae, suscipit dolor. Fusce a eros sed magna
            varius semper. Aliquam eget aliquet erat. Donec non sem ac erat consequat finibus. Aenean congue imperdiet
            feugiat. Mauris lobortis, elit in tempor laoreet, libero est bibendum massa, ut fringilla augue enim eget
            velit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Proin ultricies, est eget sodales
            ornare, nulla elit luctus lectus, et pulvinar odio lacus eget tellus.</p>

        Choose File-&gt;Settings tab: under ‘General’ tab disable SSL verification (as self-signed
        certificate is used).
        <p><strong>API</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dignissim ligula sit amet
            dui elementum placerat. Proin ultricies sollicitudin varius. Etiam erat mauris, eleifend sed risus non,
            vulputate congue sapien. In a orci tempor, venenatis leo vitae, suscipit dolor. Fusce a eros sed magna
            varius semper. Aliquam eget aliquet erat. Donec non sem ac erat consequat finibus. Aenean congue imperdiet
            feugiat. Mauris lobortis, elit in tempor laoreet, libero est bibendum massa, ut fringilla augue enim eget
            velit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Proin ultricies, est eget sodales
            ornare, nulla elit luctus lectus, et pulvinar odio lacus eget tellus.</p>
        <p><strong>API</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dignissim ligula sit amet
            dui elementum placerat. Proin ultricies sollicitudin varius. Etiam erat mauris, eleifend sed risus non,
            vulputate congue sapien. In a orci tempor, venenatis leo vitae, suscipit dolor. Fusce a eros sed magna
            varius semper. Aliquam eget aliquet erat. Donec non sem ac erat consequat finibus. Aenean congue imperdiet
            feugiat. Mauris lobortis, elit in tempor laoreet, libero est bibendum massa, ut fringilla augue enim eget
            velit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Proin ultricies, est eget sodales
            ornare, nulla elit luctus lectus, et pulvinar odio lacus eget tellus.</p>
        <p><strong>API</strong> Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras dignissim ligula sit amet
            dui elementum placerat. Proin ultricies sollicitudin varius. Etiam erat mauris, eleifend sed risus non,
            vulputate congue sapien. In a orci tempor, venenatis leo vitae, suscipit dolor. Fusce a eros sed magna
            varius semper. Aliquam eget aliquet erat. Donec non sem ac erat consequat finibus. Aenean congue imperdiet
            feugiat. Mauris lobortis, elit in tempor laoreet, libero est bibendum massa, ut fringilla augue enim eget
            velit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus. Proin ultricies, est eget sodales
            ornare, nulla elit luctus lectus, et pulvinar odio lacus eget tellus.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you share your code on stackblitz

Comment: What font are you using ? It's most probably an issue with the font not being supported by jspdf. Try converting your font to 'Helvetica' just to test if it prints ok, to make sure this is the problem. If so, you can try adding your font so that jspdf recognizes it. check out https://www.devlinpeck.com/content/jspdf-custom-font#:~:text=Adding%20Custom%20Fonts%20to%20jsPDF,of%20your%20desired%20font%20file.&text=Once%20you%20have%20your%20.,to%20this%20jsPDF%20Font%20Converter.